# how to hide the tags and category in the front page

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms

My site is `http://nbmdemo.16mb.com/`

How do I hide **tags:featured**

Also in `http://nbmdemo.16mb.com/?q=node/1`

Same thing with: **Category: Demo Articles**

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it by going to **admin/structure/types/manage/YOUR-CONTENT-TYPE/display** and just drag the field(s) info the **Disabled** section.

[image: Shows image of manage display with a red arrow dragging body to Disabled section]

Answer (score 0):

That seems like you are showing nodes of content type article, if not substitute the content type you are displaying.

Go to the admin area > structure > content type > [article or your content type] > manage display.

Set the "tags" field to hidden, for both "label" and "format". Depending on the display type you are using, you may need to go up into the top right corner of this page and switch from "Default" to "Teaser" and modify those display settings as well.

helpful screenshot:

[image: Imgur]